# Python: How to reverse a list in a new dictionary without reversing the original

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists say:

```
dic = {"foo" : [1,3,5,6] , "bar" : [5, 3, 8, 4]}
```

I'm trying to create a new dictionary of the reverse of these lists without corrupting the original

I have even tried things like

```
list1 =  dic["foo"]
list2 = list1.reverse()
newDic = {}
newDic["foo"] = list2
```

But it seems that `dic["A"]`, `list1` and `list2` are all pointing to the same memory location.
In other words, `dic["foo"]` also gets reversed in this process, which is not what I want!!!
is there any easy way around this?

Comment: are you still having problems? If not, please mark the answer that helped you as the solution. It will help others in the future who may have a similar issue as you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do the whole dictionary try this one liner:

`newDic =  {key:value[::-1] for key,value in dic.iteritems()}`

If you just want to do one list try this:

```
list1 =  dic["foo"]
newDic = {}
newDic["foo"] = list1[::-1]
```

`list.reverse()` will change the list itself. Try `list[::-1]` and it will return a new copy of a reversed list

Answer (score 1):

`list1.reverse()` is an in-place reversal. Use the function `reversed(list1)` instead, which does not modify the list it is called on.

Specifically:

```
dic = {"foo" : [1,3,5,6] , "bar" : [5, 3, 8, 4]}
list1 = dic["foo"]
list2 = list(reversed(list1))
newDic = {}
newDic["foo"] = list2
```

Note that `reversed(list1)` returns a [generator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=yield#generator-expressions) and you want the full list, so that's why `list` is called on it above.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `list2 = list1.reverse()`

[list.reverse()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method will reverse same list.

like

```
>>> a = [66.25, 333, 333, 1, 1234.5]
>>> a.reverse()
>>> a
[1234.5, 1, 333, 333, 66.25]
```

Return type of `reverse` is `None`

```
>>> a = [66.25, 333, 333, 1, 1234.5]
>>> b = a.reverse()
>>> b
>>> print b
None
```

So in your case `list2 = None`.

Another problem is

your are accessing **`f00`** and key is **`foo`**

Comment: sorry! Excuse the typo!

Comment: No problem. You get the answer I think :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
list2 = []
for e in reversed(list1):
   list2.append(e)
```

list1.reverse() reverses the original list. rather you could do in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your real problem is creating a copy of the list, so you can do

```
list2 = list(list1)
list2.reverse()
```

or

```
list2 = list1[:]
list2.reverse()
```